# Can I modify the view in a UITableView section header without recreating the whole thing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` in Plain view, with really long header text for a section. I want to truncate the text in the middle rather than the end, i.e. set `lineBreakMode` on `UILabel` to `UILineBreakModeMiddleTruncation`, but I don't want to have to recreate the whole view myself in `-tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` because that's all I'm changing and I want to keep the default UITableView look.

I fear this is not easily done.

Is this possible? If so, how?

And, if not possible, how can I recreate the look in `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think there is any other method, you can't do it except using,

```
-tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:
```